# How to create/copy Branch using Sublicpse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I developing a Eclipse plugin which creates  branch. I'm using Subclipse, but this does not work. Error message: svn: E195000: A path under version control is needed for this operation

It works by command line:

svn cp svn://host/myRepo/trunk svn://host/myRepo/branches/aBrach -m "Please, copy"

But in my Eclpse plugin, I can't : (

```
ISVNRepositoryLocation  location = SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getRepositories().getRepository("svn://host/myRepo");

SVNUrl origin = location.getUrl().appendPath("trunk");
SVNUrl branch = location.getUrl().appendPath("branches").appendPath("aBranch");

ISVNClientAdapter svnClient = null;

try{
    svnClient = location.getSVNClient();
    svnClient.copy(origin, branch, "Please, copy", SVNRevision.BASE, true);
}catch(Exception e){
    location.returnSVNClient(svnClient);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want SVNRevision.HEAD

BASE can only be used if the source is a working copy.